# Is there a way to enter text for Specific cells with in a range selected?

Tags: excel, vba

New to Vba excel and I can't figure out how to enter in text to range of cells that is within an already selected range of cells.

I have a list of data going down about 10K rows. I have added a new header attempting to add text to it for each row going down.

So basically if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> (in the data set I have) and shift over to my new header I have the data range I want but I can't figure how to enter in text under the header within this range. Hope this all makes sense.

I have already tried this.

So I have only gotten as far as selecting the range through VBA. Ideally I want the new header to be able to run "If then" checks and update each cell under the new header accordingly. So if cell "H8" says whatever then "P8" will is where I want the result.

```
Sub Card_type_test()

    Dim CT As String

    CT = ActiveCell.Value

    If CT = "AMERICAN EXPRESS" Then
        ActiveCell(1, 9).Value = "AMEX2"
    ElseIf CT = "MASTERCARD" Then
        ActiveCell(1, 9).Value = "MC2"
    ElseIf CT = "VISA" Then
        ActiveCell(1, 9).Value = "VISA2"
    Else
    End If

End Sub

Sub Selecting_correct_Cells()

    Range(Range("P8"), Range("H8").End(xlDown)).Select

End Sub
```

The first Sub was a test to see if the "if then" statement worked. Which it does if I am highlighting "H8" for example as the active cell. The last sub is the range selected I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you have to use `VBA` for this? can you not just use `Formula's`?

Comment: To add to @Zac's comment, would a simple `VLOOKUP()` table not work?

Comment: Your right. I guess i was over complicating things